# Read each JSON object from the JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json, integer

Question: Read each JSON object from the JSON array. For each JSON object, parse the values
of the fields - Id, Model, Make, Year, and Colour.

This is my code:

JSONArray array =

```
for (int i= 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String Make = JSONObject.getString("Make");
    int id = JSONObject.getInt("Id");
    int year = JSONObject.getInt("year");
    String Model = JSONObject.getString("Model");
    String Colour = JSONObject.getString("Colour");
}
```

What I am doing wrong because I am getting errors. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me through.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **exact** errors you're getting.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to replace `JSONObject.get...()` with `object.get...()`

Comment: If possible share response/output for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of JSONObject.getXXX() you should use object.getXXX(). Because you need to extract the content out of the object reference variable.

So your code should be like below and it should work fine.

```
for (int i= 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String Make = object.getString("Make");
    int id = object.getInt("Id");
    int year = object.getInt("year");
    String Model = object.getString("Model");
    String Colour = object.getString("Colour");
}
```

Comment: But it says as a error  for (int i= 0; i < array.length(); ++i) code is incomplete.

Comment: Please post the error here and also which JSONArray implementation you have used. Please mention the imports here.